# Able query only admin database

Tags: mongodb

I just upgraded to 2.6. I run the `authSchemaUpgrade`. But after that, I managed to remove all users from the database (Its a private small database, so that is nothing too bad). Now I have created a new user `admin`:

```js
{
        "_id" : "admin.admin",
        "user" : "admin",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ]
}
```

After I have `db.auth("admin","..")` on the admin database I should be able to query any other databases too, but after I do:

user otherDatabase
   show collections

I get:

```
2014-06-09T09:33:36.853+0000 error: {
        "$err" : "not authorized for query on otherDatabase.system.namespaces",
        "code" : 13
} at src/mongo/shell/query.js:131
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your admin user the role `readWriteAnyDatabase` in order to allow that user to query other databases.

You may want to also consider giving your admin user `dbAdminAnyDatabase` and `clusterAdmin` roles.